# Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, magento, innodb

I have a issue in mysql as the result my mgento 2 website crashes always. Please see this error. How can i solve this. Website is hosted in AWS .

```
[2021-07-19 15:42:32] main.ERROR: SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections [] []
[2021-07-19 15:42:34] main.ERROR: SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections [] []
[2021-07-19 15:42:54] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 500000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes. [] []
[2021-07-19 15:43:05] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 500000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes. [] []
```

Comment: How much spare ram do you have?  128M is quite small for `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

Answer (score 2):

To determine the optimal [`innodb_buffer_pool_size`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size), run [this query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27341/209994) written by [@RolandoMySQLDBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/877/rolandomysqldba)

```sql
SELECT CEILING(Total_InnoDB_Bytes*1.6/POWER(1024,3)) RIBPS FROM
(SELECT SUM(data_length+index_length) Total_InnoDB_Bytes
FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB') A;
```

This will give you the RIBPS, Recommended InnoDB Buffer Pool Size, based on all InnoDB Data and Indexes, with an additional 60%.

In my case, the value is `1` (GB), so you have 2 options:

#### A) Configure InnoDB Buffer Pool Size using config file

1. Edit `my.cnf` (MySQL) or `mariadb-server.cnf` (MariaDB), and add one line under the `[mysqld]` section, e.g.:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G
```

2. Restart your MySQL Database

*OR*

#### B) Configure InnoDB Buffer Pool Size Online

`1`GB is `1073741824` bytes. Run the following while logged in as `root`:

```sql
mysqld> SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size=1073741824;
```

Confirm the new value by running:

```sql
mysqld> SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size/1024/1024/1024;
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento can increase the memory for processing a large amount of data by using memory engines instead of InnoDB. The algorithm increases the memory value for the max_heap_table_size and tmp_table_size MySQL parameters.

When the allocated memory size for a temporary table will be greater than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size, the error message is written to the Magento log.

To prevent this error message, you need to update default Batching configuration of catalog_category_product (Category Products) indexer because "Current batch size: 100000".

Note: Decrease the batchRowsCount to resolve the error.